# Using pgsql_fdw in a function result "ERROR: cache lookup failed for type 0"

Tags: postgresql

We want to use pgsql_fdw to select a table of remote postgresql database. When we
select the table in a session it is okay, but when we use the foreign table in a funciton 
it turns out "ERROR:  cache lookup failed for type 0". Does anybody know why?

### 1. base information

```
skytf=> \d ft_test;
       Foreign table "skytf.ft_test"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 id     | integer               | 
 name   | character varying(32) | 
Server: pgsql_srv


skytf=> \des+ pgsql_srv
                                                List of foreign servers
   Name    | Owner | Foreign-data wrapper | Access privileges | Type | Version |                Options                 
-----------+-------+----------------------+-------------------+------+---------+----------------------------------------
 pgsql_srv | skytf | pgsql_fdw            |                   |      |         | {host=127.0.0.1,port=1923,dbname=mydb}
(1 row)
```

### 2. destination table

```
mydb=> \d test
             Table "mydb.test"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 id     | integer               | 
 name   | character varying(32) | 
Indexes:
    "idx_test_1" btree (id)
```

### 3. function

```
 CREATE or replace FUNCTION  func_sync_bill() RETURNS INTEGER  AS $$
    BEGIN

     begin
      insert into test_tf (id,name) select id,name from ft_test;
      return 1;
     end; 
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

### 4. it works in a session

```
skytf=> create table test_tf(id integer,name varchar(32));
CREATE TABLE

skytf=> insert into test_tf select * from ft_test;
INSERT 0 1990000
```

### 5. function call error

```
skytf=> truncate table test_tf;
TRUNCATE TABLE

skytf=> select func_sync_bill();
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for type 0
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into test_tf (id,name) select id,name from ft_test"
PL/pgSQL function "func_sync_bill" line 5 at SQL statement
```

When I call the function func_sync_bill() which will select a foreign table, it generates the the error.

Is this a bug of pgsql_fdw?

Comment: I don't know how to format the question,anybody can tell me?

Comment: The formatting is explained if you click on the little orange question mark in the upper right corner. If also then shows a link "advanced help" which leads you to: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: nobody can answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the foreign data wrapper or plpgsql or something.  Given that the `\d` commands are working, I would expect that the catalogs are fine, which suggests that the real problem is data corruption although the fact that it works outside the function suggests that maybe that's not the case.

things to do to troubleshoot would be to try to rewrite your function as an SQL language function instead of plpgsql and see if that fixes the problem.  if it does, you have a workaround.  Also try on more recent minor versions of PostgreSQL.  If the problem is fixed, then great.  But if not, this is a case where a bug report to the project may result in getting the problem fixed.

Comment: finaly I use a dynamic statements in a function  avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Finaly I use dynamic statements avoid the problem.
```

**--dynamic statements**

```
skytf=> CREATE or replace FUNCTION  func_sync_bill() RETURNS INTEGER  AS $$
skytf$>     BEGIN
skytf$>      begin
skytf$>         EXECUTE 'insert into test_tf (id,name) select id,name from ft_test';
skytf$>        return 0;     
skytf$>      end; 
skytf$>     END;
skytf$> $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';    
CREATE FUNCTION
```

**--try again**

```
skytf=> truncate table test_tf;
TRUNCATE TABLE

skytf=> select func_sync_bill();
 func_sync_bill 
----------------
              0
(1 row)

skytf=> select count(*) from test_tf;
  count  
---------
 1990000
(1 row)
```